# Is this sentence right or wrong?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> At this time/At this point, we can tell a boy and a man apart by what they do.

I want to express the situation like a disaster suddenly happened in a family.

Is my sentence right or wrong, can you understand it?

Answer (score 1):

I think your sentence is fine, but you might consider changing your opening clause:

> **In times like these**, we can tell a boy and a man apart by what they do.

This expression is often used to refer to a current episode of trials or troubles.

There is nothing wrong with “At this time” or “At this point”, but neither of those implies a time of hardship the way “In times like these” does.

Answer (score 0):

In part, what you're trying to say seems a bit odd because it's so close to an [existing idiom](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/separate+the+men+from+the+boys) in English. It almost sounds as if you were trying to use  *separate the men from the boys* or *sort out the men from the boys* but failed.

> This is what separates the men from the boys.

Answer (score -2):

It's understandable, but it's not completely clear.  You wrote,

"...,at this time/at this point, we can tell *a boy and a man apart* **by what** **they do**."

I would rewrite it to say,

"...,at this time/at this point, we can tell a boy and a man apart **based upon what each one does**."

That doesn't mean yours is wrong; it just means that mine points out the boy and man better.  Yours is fine, however, and it's a very good sentence.

Comment: I think this suggestion is a step in the wrong direction. The brevity of the original has a nice ring to it.

Comment: The other one is briefer and I did say hers is a very good sentence; I just liked separating a boy from a man in the following clause to show how different they are.

Comment: You said that your version "points out the boy and man **better**” [emphasis added]. I’m just saying that I disagree. I wouldn’t want the OP or other learners to come here and think your version constitutes an improvement.

Comment: Okay, you disagree. It may be a matter of semantics.  In essence, they mean the same thing pretty much, but I thought my version was more stylistic and added emphasis. If it were trying to tell two boys apart, I would definitely not care and say "by what they do".  If you disagree, it is merely preference.  I said that neither was wrong and I think you would agree with that.